# Is it possible to have a communication from a application installed on the WSL2 system to VsCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

Is it possible to have a bidirectional communication from an application that is installed on the connected OS ( wsl2 ) and the VsCode?

I have a use case where I need to have a javascript application to ask for a password and I need to create a prompt in the vscode. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean a web application, since asking for a password in a JavaScript console app should be a bit obvious, but can you clarify your use case to be sure?

Comment: i mean VsCode, as far as i know, the desktop version is almost the same as web version. I'm trying to find out can I invoke the application on the debian ( wsl2 ) which would create a prompt in VsCode. of course, I would use the integrated vscode terminal

Comment: I mean what type of *JavaScript* application are you creating in VSCode that you want to run on Debian?  Console app?  Web App?  Something else?

Comment: this, https://github.com/woss/git-gpg-remote-sign  is the poc, now it needs a server to run, but if I can somehow ask make the remote-signer talk to the vscode ( preferably in the browser)  then I am not tied to the server and I can have more freedom to choose how to sign my commits.

Comment: While there's almost certainly a way to do it, I'm just not going to be able to follow the flow of the app without more time than I can invest.  If you can get an [MRE}(https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it *might* help.  Or perhaps someone else can look at your repo and grok it more quickly than I.

Comment: i don't think this is my repo specific, also there is a compose file that sets up the stuff in painless mode. basically this question is quite generic, can a javascript file ( bundled and executed via the node ) talk to the vscode which is running the shell in the integrated terminal or not.

Comment: I think I see what you are asking, and if so, the answer seems to be "not in the integrated terminal, no" per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38216924/11810933).  However, you can use `"console": "externalTerminal" and VSCode will pop up a separate debugger window where user input is accepted.  Is that what you are looking for?